# UPDATE dando erro mas atualiza banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, login, sql-update

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou criando uma página de *login* em que preciso gravar no banco de dados MySQL a data e hora em que foi efetuado o *login* do usuário. No banco de dados tenho uma tabela mais ou menos assim:

```
____________________________________________________
|  nome  | login  |  senha   |       login_on      | 
----------------------------------------------------
| Sarah  | Sarah@ | Sarah123 | 22/07/2016 16:30:24 |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Quando realizo um *login* é exibida a mensagem de erro na tela como mostrado na imagem, mas quando entro no banco de dados e dou um *refresh* é mostrada a tabela atualizada com o campo `login_on` preenchido. Não entendo, alguém sabe me dizer o porque ele realiza o UPDATE e mostra mensagem de erro?

Lá vai o código:

```
<?php //Página de login de agentes

include("conection.php");
if((isset($_POST['login']))&&(isset($_POST['senha']))){

    session_start();
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $date = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");

    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];

    $query = mysqli_query($conecta,"SELECT login_ag, senha_ag FROM agente WHERE login_ag LIKE '$login' AND senha_ag LIKE '$senha'");
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($rows > 0){
        $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
        $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
        $sql = mysqli_query($conecta,"UPDATE agente SET login_on = '$date' WHERE login_ag = '$login' AND senha_ag = '$senha'");
        if(mysqli_query($conecta,$sql)){
            echo "login_on modificado com sucesso!";
        }else{ echo "erro ao relizar o login_on";}
        //header('location:paginadeagente.php');    
        //echo $login.' '.$senha;
        echo $date;
    }else{
        unset ($_SESSION['login']);//<--destruindo variável
        unset ($_SESSION['senha']);//<--destruindo variável
        echo "<script>alert('Usuário ou senha incorretos!');</script>";
        //header('location:login.php');
    }

    //$End = microtime(true);
    //$Final = number_format(($End-$Start),6);

    //echo "<br><br>"."tempo gasto: $Final";
}

mysqli_close($conecta);

?>
```

Comment: você esta usando `mysqli_query` dentro de `mysqli_query`, a sua variavel `$sql` deve ser apenas uma string; tente desta maneira.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly assim      $sql = ($conecta,"UPDATE agente SET login_on = '$date' WHERE login_ag = '$login' AND senha_ag = '$senha'");

Comment: a varaivel $sql tem que ser apenas uma string "UPDATE agente SET login_on = '$date' WHERE login_ag = '$login' AND senha_ag = '$senha'";

Comment: @RafaelAcioly assim: --> $sql = "UPDATE agente SET login_on = '$date' WHERE login_ag = '$login' AND senha_ag = '$senha'";

Comment: obrigada! deu certo!

Comment: @RafaelAcioly escreve a resposta

Comment: já publiquei a resposta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua *query* esta sendo executada uma dentro da outra:

```
//primeira ocorrência
$sql = mysqli_query($conecta,"UPDATE agente SET login_on = '$date' WHERE login_ag = '$login' AND senha_ag = '$senha'");

//segunda ocorrência
if(mysqli_query($conecta,$sql)){
   echo "login_on modificado com sucesso!";
}else{
   echo "erro ao relizar o login_on";
}
```

Declare a varaivel `$sql` apenas como ums string normal:

```
$sql = "UPDATE agente SET login_on = '$date' WHERE login_ag = '$login' AND senha_ag = '$senha'"
```

Depois use ela normalmente:

```
if(mysqli_query($conecta,$sql)){
 echo "login_on modificado com sucesso!";
}else{
 echo "erro ao relizar o login_on";
}
```

Comment: vlw @RafaelAcioly :)

Answer (score 2):

Parace ter um erro de lógica no bloco abaixo:

```
    //primeira ocorrência
    $sql = mysqli_query($conecta,"UPDATE agente SET login_on = '$date' WHERE login_ag = '$login' AND senha_ag = '$senha'");
    if(mysqli_query($conecta,$sql)){//segunda ocorrência 
       echo "login_on modificado com sucesso!";
    }else{
       echo "erro ao relizar o login_on";
    }
```

É executada duas vezes a mesma consulta sendo que a segunda já inválida pois `$sql` não é mais um string e sim um resouce ou false.

Comment: Obrigada @rray :)